# How to set my local javascript variable as a json data on remote website

Tags: javascript, json

I have a javascript code on my website, there is a variable:

```
var remoteJsonVar;
```

On the other hand there is a json file on a remote website

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.stackoverflow.com

I need to set the variable **remoteJsonVar** to this remote jason data.

I am sure that it is very simple, but I can't find the solution.

A small working example would be nice.

Comment: What is a "JSON script"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're trying to get the data from a different *origin*, if you want to do this entirely client-side, you'd use [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) rather than just JSON because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Facebook supports this if you just add a `callback` parameter to your query string, e.g.:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.stackoverflow.com?callback=foo
```

Then you define a function in your script (at global scope) which has the name you give in that `callback` parameter, like this:

```
function foo(data) {
    remoteJsonVar = data;
}
```

You trigger it by creating a `script` element and setting the `src` to the desired URL, e.g.:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.stackoverflow.com?callback=foo";
document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
```

Note that the call to your function will be *asynchronous*.

Now, since you may want to have more than one outstanding request, and you probably don't want to leave that callback lying around when you're done, you may want to be a bit more sophisticated and create a random callback name, etc. Here's a complete example:

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ilafow) | [Live source](http://jsbin.com/ilafow/edit)

```
(function() {

  // Your variable; if you prefer, it could be a global,
  // but I try to avoid globals where I can
  var responseJsonVar;

  // Hook up the button
  hookEvent(document.getElementById("theButton"),
            "click",
            function() {
      var callbackName, script;

      // Get a random name for our callback
      callbackName = "foo" + new Date().getTime() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);

      // Create it
      window[callbackName] = function(data) {
          responseJsonVar = data;
          display("Got the data, <code>shares = " +
            data["http://www.stackoverflow.com"].shares +
            "</code>");

          // Remove our callback (`delete` with `window` properties
          // fails on some versions of IE, so we fall back to setting
          // the property to `undefined` if that happens)
          try {
              delete window[callbackName];
          }
          catch (e) {
              window[callbackName] = undefined;
          }
      }

      // Do the JSONP request
      script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = "https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.stackoverflow.com&callback=" + callbackName;
      document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
      display("Request started");
  });

  // === Basic utility functions

  function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = msg;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }

  function hookEvent(element, eventName, handler) {
    // Very quick-and-dirty, recommend using a proper library,
    // this is just for the purposes of the example.
    if (typeof element.addEventListener !== "undefined") {
      element.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
    }
    else if (typeof element.attachEvent !== "undefined") {
      element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, function(event) {
        return handler(event || window.event);
      });
    }
    else {
      throw "Browser not supported.";
    }
  }
})();
```

Note that when you use JSONP, you're putting a lot of trust in the site at the other end. Technically, JSONP isn't JSON at all, it's giving the remote site the opportunity to *run code* on your page. If you trust the other end, great, but just remember the potential for abuse.

You haven't mentioned using any libraries, so I haven't used any above, but I would recommend looking at a good JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). A lot of the code above has already been written for you with a good library. For instance, here's the above using jQuery:

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/akapet) | [Live source](http://jsbin.com/akapet/edit)

```
jQuery(function($) {

  // Your variable
  var responseJsonVar;

  $("#theButton").click(function() {
    display("Sending request");
    $.get("https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.stackoverflow.com&callback=?",
          function(data) {
            responseJsonVar = data;
            display("Got the data, <code>shares = " +
              data["http://www.stackoverflow.com"].shares +
              "</code>");
          },
          "jsonp");
  });

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});
```

Comment: Or just download it and parse.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Client-side, you can't if it's on a different origin. But if you mean with a server rather than client-side, yes, absolutely.

Comment: Oh, good point. Of course. Meanwhile I never really understood why JSON-P is allowed to circumvent SOP.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The SOP never applied to `script` elements, and by the time vendors might have considered do that, so many people were using CDNs or other different origins for static resources I figure (this is supposition) it would have been unpopular. Naturally, again, there's a **huge** amount of trust required, since you're basically giving that other site full access to do whatever they want to your page. ~shudder~ :-)

Comment: Indeed. Personally I proxy _all_ "dynamic" external requests through webserver. It's rarely a dumb pass-through, but still I'm not sure how much safer this _really_ makes me. But hey.