# do we have to enable JSONP on server

Tags: jsp, jsonp

i've created an application which uses JSONP . the application works perfectly on my local server. but when deployed in live server it's not showing the apt output. i doubt where the live server does'nt support JSONP..so do there anything like that in which we have to enable something for JSONP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these stuffs..........

**[What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about?rq=1)**

**[JSONP enabled by default](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1304)**

**[JSONP with node.js express](http://vaboone.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/jsonp-with-node-js-express/)**

**[JSONP, Quickly](http://niryariv.wordpress.com/2009/05/05/jsonp-quickly/)**

**[How do I set up JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519209/how-do-i-set-up-jsonp)**