# How to make a jsonp request

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I need to do some cross site scripting.  The block of code below contains the method of jsonp, the method returns as if it failed, but when I change it to be a get request I then have success.  I need to be able to a successful response using the jsonp method.  The following can be ruled out.  The response is valid json and this param is in the url ?callback=JSON_CALLBACK.  Here is the json I receive from doing the http request and the code block that executes this code.

http response status code 200

```
[{"cube":"1" ,"points":"160"},{"cube":"2","points":"690"},{"cube":"3","points":"331"}]
```

code block

```
 var myApp = angular.module('test', []);

    myApp.controller('UserCtrl', function($scope, users) {
        $scope.usersPerCube = users.getUsers();
    })

    myApp.factory('users', function($http) {
       return {
         getUsers: function() {
           var deferred = $q.defer();
           var url = "http://localhost/api/api/index.php/analytics/UsersPerCube?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
         $http.get(url).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                //this always gets called
                console.log(status);
                deferred.reject(status);
            });
            return deferred.promise;

     }
   }
```

Note that I have edited my server side code and now receive

```
"angular.callbacks._1( {"cube":"1","points":"160"},{"cube":"2","points":"690"},{"cube":"3","points":"331"})"
```

***UPDATE***
The above is valid and now the success method is executing.  I just need to figure out how to parse the objects.  I will post again once I figure out the answer.

Comment: Does the server you're requesting against understand JSONP (notably the `callback` query-string value)?

Comment: If your response is valid JSON then it is not valid JSONP. JSONP is JSON data wrapped with a function. To the point of @Alxandr, are you sure you're getting back JSONP?

Comment: I have everything this stack overflow suggests to make it valid jsonp on the server side. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519209/how-do-i-set-up-jsonp .  Also angular responses with angular.callbacks._1 which means it recognizes it as jsonp.  I'm just not sure what I should do with the response now.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have decided to give a detailed description of how to do a [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) request so others will not run into the same troubles as I did.

```
myApp.factory('users', function($http) {
       return {
         getUsers: function() {
           var deferred = $q.defer();
           var url = "http://localhost/api/api/index.php/analytics/UsersPerCube?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
         $http.get(url).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                //this always gets called
                console.log(status);
                deferred.reject(status);
            });
            return deferred.promise;

     }
```

Notice that the url contains `?callback=JSON_CALLBACK`.   [Here is a nice stackoverflow on that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066002/parsing-jsonp-http-jsonp-response-in-angular-js)  Once you get the response then you'll receive a json like the one below.

```
"angular.callbacks._1( {"cube":"1","points":"160"},{"cube":"2","points":"690"},{"cube":"3","points":"331"})"
```

[Here is a nice stackoverflow on that subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344933/angularjs-jsonp-not-working)

Now the one part that got me is that the server has to return the `GET` param, `callback`.  Here is a good tutorial for that.  http://niryariv.wordpress.com/2009/05/05/jsonp-quickly/ So the json looks like the one above.

Well, I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: what was your response content type ? i am having one small issue, browser is not able to display response as it forces to download it. and response content type is "application/jsonp"

Comment: Any reason not to use `$http.jsonp()` and to manually create a promise, since the former already returns one?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make several JSONP requests through $http service, you should use a little hack. Agular change JSON_CALLBACK to internal value, and best way to use next solution: put this js code into your returned js-file:

```
var callbackId = '_' + (angular.callbacks.counter - 1).toString(36);
angular.callbacks[callbackId](/* YOUR JSON */);
```

To be sure that this code will work for you, please check **createHttpBackend** method in angular sources.