# Angularjs $http cant get data but can get from $jquery.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I tired to get data off a api using jquery.ajax() and it **works fine**

here is the code for that:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://api.somesite.com/api?format=json",
  type: "GET", //it works with POST as well
  dataType: 'jsonp',
 })
  .done(function( data ) {
    if ( console && console.log ) {
      console.log( "Sample of data:", data );
    }
  });
```

Now i wanted to do the same with angularjs so i did the following

**First i did this:**

```
var req = {
 method: 'GET',
 url: "http://api.somesite.com/api?format=json",
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': "application/json",
  },
}

 $http(req).then(function(response){
          console.log(response.data);
        });
```

i get this in the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.somesite.com/api?format=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**Then i tried this:**

```
 $http.jsonp('http://api.somesite.com/api?format=json', {
    headers: {
        "content-type":"application/json",
        "Accept" : "application/json"
    }}).success(function(data, status) {
         console.log(status);
          console.log(data);
        }).
        error(function(data, status) {
          console.log(status);
          console.log(data);
        });
```

I get error code **404** and data as **undefined**

Kindly do tell how to accomplish. I do not have access to the serve or the api so i cannot modify the api in any way.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS: how to make a jsonp request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916362/angularjs-how-to-make-a-jsonp-request) (the jQuery one is jsonp, the angular one isn't)

Comment: read `$http.jsonp` docs and add proper `callback` param to url